# Блок для группировки операторов

Tags: javascript

Ниже я отметил строку, так вот, у меня возник вопрос.

Это объект в объекте или блок для группировки операторов?

И как отличить **{}** от объекта и блока для группировки операторов?

```js
let convert = {
  name: "Opa",
  age: 120,

  toString() { // Метка
    return `{name: "${this.name}", age: ${this.age}}`;
  } // Метка
};
```

Comment: Это свойство объекта. Такое же как и другие свойства, только в качестве значения выступает не число или строка, а функция. Возможно в такой записи будет привычнее: `toString: function() { ... },`.

Comment: Значит это функция в объекте?

Comment: Да, это функция в объекте. А т.к. функция тоже объект, то получается, что это объект в объекте.